# Как использовать 2 графика?

Tags: javascript, html, диаграммы, график, google-chart

На темплате django вывести 2 графика.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#curving-the-lines

и

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#example

Но выводится только один из них ...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный код:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
      <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение - объединил оба скрипта в один (все в одну функцию)